# after installation angular is not working on my windows 10 home

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

when i gone to this folder it contain all the files but ng codes are not working

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 14.17.3 (x64) and npm.

C:\Users\raj&sakthi>ng -v
'sakthi\AppData\Roaming\npm\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\raj\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng.js'
[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m {
  code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
  requireStack: []
}

C:\Users\raj&sakthi>node -v
v14.17.3

C:\Users\raj&sakthi>npm -v
6.14.13
```

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: npm install -g @angular/cli---->admin mode

Comment: I wonder why your path is `C:\Users\raj&sakthi` but the command is looking in `C:\Users\raj\node_modules`. Where's the `&sakthi`? Could this be the problem?

Comment: In the errors some things say `sakthi` and some things say `raj` -- is having `&` in the user name a good idea? Maybe that breaks things...

Answer (score 0):

try installing Angular CLI globally:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: did but not works